split dataframe by multiple lists. loop?
I have a dictionary of lists of student numbers, and a dataframe that contains those student numbers and more. I want to separate that dataframe into multiple dataframes, each which contains the rows for the student numbers in each list.
This code gives me the output I want, just trying to figure out how to make a dictionary of the dataframes
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
    'UW ID': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    'Term': [201001, 201101, 201201, 201201, 201001, 201001, 201101, 201201, 201201]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

student_numbers = {"F10": [1, 2, 7], "F11": [3, 4, 8], "F12": [5, 6]}

for item in student_numbers:
    grads = df[df['UW ID'].isin(student_numbers[item])]
    print(grads)


What do you need help with exactly? It looks like you can just loop over student_numbers, right? Did you try that? But then to store the result, you couldn't use individual variables; instead you could use a dict; see How do I create variable variables?

After the edit, it's still not clear what you need help with. What have you tried to create a dict? If you haven't tried it, do that first; it might be easier than you expected :) BTW the title doesn't match the question body anymore, since you have a loop.

You can do it this way and create a dictionary of dataframes with the keys same as in your student_numbers dictionary.  No need for an explicity for-loop, you can use dictionary comprehension:
r_map = {e:k for k, v in student_numbers.items() for e in v}
dfs = dict(tuple(df.groupby(df['UW ID'].map(r_map))))

Outputs:
#dfs['F10']
   UW ID    Term
0      1  201001
1      2  201101
6      7  201101
  

#dfs['F11']
   UW ID    Term
2      3  201201
3      4  201201
7      8  201201

and,
#dfs['F12']
   UW ID    Term
4      5  201001
5      6  201001


I'd have used the same approach, but note that it only works if the lists are not overlapping.

@mozway How do/did you handle overlapping list?

I guess a loop with reindex, which will be O(n*m).

thanks! The lists shouldnt be overlapping, unless Ive done something wrong. I will have to try this one out, the other solution with the loop worked for the timebeing.

Perhaps this solves your problem?
# create a dict to store data by student groups
student_numbers_with_data = {}

# iterate through dictionary items
for student_group, student_ids in student_numbers.items():
    student_group_data = df[df['UW ID'].isin(student_ids)]
    # store in new dict
    student_numbers_with_data[student_group] = student_group_data
    # print results
    print(f"Data for student group {student_group}")
    print(student_group_data)


that does it! Thanks! I'm still working out how so much of this works this has been so helpful

Note that this searches the full dataframe for each key. Thus the complexity is O(n*m) (n = number of rows, m = number of keys), you can get O(n+m) with @Scott's approach if the lists are not overlapping.

You want to reference "pieces" of the original dataframe that correspond to the filters that you specified. You also probably want to set the student_id as index to speed up the process. Try this:
df = df.set_index('UW ID')
dfs = {k: df.loc[v] for k, v in student_numbers.items()}
#         ^ use df.loc[v].copy() if you want a new object
dfs['F10']


this assumes that the student_number matches the data, otherwise you'll get a KeyError (in that case you can use .isin, but it is a bit less efficient).

This gives me outputs that are off by 1. also in the actual data set the student IDs arent sequential they are bunch of numbers

they should not be off by 1, you have the dataframe with the UW ID as index instead of as a column, use .reset_index(). Also the fact that they are not sequential would not matter. .loc matches index values, not row numbers

ooooh sorry I missed that line. ok. It works, but it does get angry where there is a dictionary item that doesnt have any matches to the data. So now I'm just figuring out if I can easily remove those or if I need to try another way. Thanks!
